# couchdb showing different record count with pagination?

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I wanted to calculate how many records couchDB has for a database. So hit the below API and it returns json which has records count as well.

```
   GET http://localhost:20984/mydb/
```

jSON

```
{
    "db_name": "mydb",
    "update_seq": "25577-g1AAAAFLeJ4mDJtXMoSQMrqYcpacSjLYwGSDA1ACqhyPljpJ7xKF0CU7gcrXYlX6QGI0vtgpWJ4lT6AKIW4tTYLACqwZ0c",
    "sizes": {
        "file": 20881199,
        "external": 11977342,
        "active": 16542736
    },
    "purge_seq": 0,
    "other": {
        "data_size": 11977342
    },
    "doc_del_count": 0,
    "doc_count": 25569,
    "disk_size": 20881199,
    "disk_format_version": 6,
    "data_size": 16542736,
    "compact_running": false,
    "cluster": {
        "q": 8,
        "n": 1,
        "w": 1,
        "r": 1
    },
    "instance_start_time": "0"
}
```

Here `doc_count` is `25569` so i assume total records are `25569`.

But when i set `document_per_page` to 100 & begin to view the records it shows 100 records for first page & 200 records for 2 pages & so on. And if  i keep doing this way it shows me more than `35000` records.

Now my question is if total records are `25569` then how couchDB is showing me records more than  `35000` with pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about `doc_count`, it reports the number of documents in the specified database.

Presuming you're using **Fauxton** and in there, you switch "Documents per page" to 100, I was able to reproduce the described behavior. When I repeatedly press the next arrow in a  short interval, the displayed data and the numbers on the paginator went out of sync. Therefore this seems to be a bug of Fauxton.

Comment: Yes I am using Fauxton. Should i report this bug ?

Comment: Check at https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues if the issue is not known already, otherwise report the bug.